# How is Odudua the Orisha of Earth?

Tags: africa, yoruba

Odudua is the Orisha (Yoruban deity) of Earth. She is said to be the personification of Earth and is the sister of Olorun, the god of the sky and ruler of the Orishas. However, his son, Oduduwa,is said to be the Orisha who created the Earth. If Odudua is the sister of Olurun, how could she have been created by her nephew, Oduduwa?